# Type Predicates for Function Types in Typed/Racket

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I'm at the early stages of designing a framework and am fooling around with `typed/racket`. Suppose I have the following types:

```
   (define-type Calculate-with-one-number (-> Number Number))
   (define-type Calculate-with-two-numbers (-> Number Number Number))
```

And I want to have a function that dispatches on type:

```
(: dispatcher (-> (U Calculate-with-one-number Calculate-with-two-numbers) Number))

(define (dispatcher f args)
   (cond [(Calculate-with-one-number? f)
          (do-something args)]
         [(Calculate-with-two-numbers? f)
          (do-something-else args)]
         [else 42]))
```

How do I create the type-predicates `Calculate-with-one-number?` and `Calculate-with-two-numbers?` in `Typed/Racket`? For non-function predicates I can use `define-predicate`. But it's not clear how to implement predicates for function types.

Comment: `define-type` should take care of that already I would presume. Perhaps a phasing issue?

Comment: That's what I assumed based on the behaviour of `struct`, but it does not appear to be the case...hence `define-predicate`: http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html?q=define-predicate#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._define-predicate%29%29

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Since I am self answering, I'm taking the liberty to clarify the gist of my question in light of the discussion of arity as a solution. The difference in arity was due to my not considering its implications when specifying the question.*

### The Problem

In `#lang typed/racket` as in many Lisps, functions, or more properly: [procedures](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=proc-t), are first class dataypes.

By default, `#lang racket` types procedures by [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) and any additional specificity in argument types must be done by contract. In `#lang typed/racket` procedures are typed both by arity and by the types of their arguments and return values due to the language's "baked-in contracts".

#### Math as an example

The [Typed Racket Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/index.html) provides an [example](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/more.html#%28part._.New_.Type_.Names%29) using [`define-type`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed%2Fracket%2Fbase..rkt%29._define-type%29%29) to define a procedure type:

```
 (define-type NN (-> Number Number))
```

This allows specifying a procedure more succinctly:

```
 ;; Takes two numbers, returns a number
 (define-type 2NN (-> Number Number Number))

 (: trigFunction1 2NN)
 (define (trigFunction1 x s)
   (* s (cos x)))

 (: quadraticFunction1 2NN)
 (define (quadraticFunction1 x b)
   (let ((x1 x))
     (+ b (* x1 x1))))
```

#### The Goal

In a domain like mathematics, it would be nice to work with more abstract procedure types because knowing that a function is cyclical between upper and lower bounds (like `cos`) versus having only one bound (e.g. our quadratic function) versus asymptotic (e.g. a hyperbolic function) provides for clearer reasoning about the problem domain. It would be nice to have access to abstractions something like:

```
 (define-type Cyclic2NN (-> Number Number Number))
 (define-type SingleBound2NN (-> Number Number Number))

 (: trigFunction1 Cyclic2NN)
 (define (trigFunction1 x s)
   (* s (cos x)))

 (: quadraticFunction1 SingleBound2NN)
 (define (quadraticFunction1 x b)
   (let ((x1 x))
     (+ b (* x1 x1))))

 (: playTone (-> Cyclic2NN))
 (define (playTone waveform)
   ...)

 (: rabbitsOnFarmGraph (-> SingleBound2NN)
 (define (rabbitsOnFarmGraph populationSize)
   ...)
```

Alas, `define-type` does not deliver this level of granularity when it comes to procedures. Even moreover, the brief false hope that we might easily wring such type differentiation for procedures manually using [`define-predicate`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html?q=make-predicate#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._make-predicate%29%29) is dashed by:

> Evaluates to a predicate for the type t, with the type (Any -> Boolean : t). t may not contain function types, or types that may refer to mutable data such as (Vectorof Integer).

Fundamentally, types have uses beyond static checking and contracts. As first class members of the language, we want to be able to dispatch our finer grained procedure types.  Conceptually, what is needed are predicates along the lines of `Cyclic2NN?` and `SingleBound2NN?`. Having only arity for dispatch using [`case-lambda`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html?q=case-lambda#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._case-lambda%29%29) just isn't enough.

### Guidance from Untyped Racket

Fortunately, Lisps are domain specific languages for writing Lisps once we peal back the curtain to reveal the wizard, and in the end we can get what we want. The key is to come at the issue the other way and ask "How canwe use the predicates `typed/racket` gives us for procedures?"

Structures are Racket's user defined data types and are the basis for extending it's type system. Structures are so powerful that even in the class based object system, "[classes and objects are implemented in terms of structure types](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define-struct.html)."

In `#lang racket` structures can be applied as procedures giving the `#:property` keyword using `prop:procedure` followed by a procedure for it's value. The documentation provides two examples:

The [first example](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._prop~3aprocedure%29%29) specifies a field of the structure to be applied as a procedure. Obviously, at least once it has been pointed out, that field must hold a value that evaluates to a procedure.

```
> ;; #lang racket
> (struct annotated-proc (base note)
     #:property prop:procedure
      (struct-field-index base))
> (define plus1 (annotated-proc
     (lambda (x) (+ x 1))
     "adds 1 to its argument"))
> (procedure? plus1)
#t
> (annotated-proc? plus1)
#t
> (plus1 10)
11
> (annotated-proc-note plus1)
"adds 1 to its argument"
```

In the [second example](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define-struct.html#%28part._struct-options%29) an anonymous procedure [lambda] is provided directly as part of the property value. The lambda takes an operand in the first position which is resolved to the value of the structure being used as a procedure. This allows accessing any value stored in any field of the structure including those which evaluate to procedures.

```
> ;; #lang racket
> (struct greeter (name)
    #:property prop:procedure
    (lambda (self other)
       (string-append
         "Hi " other
          ", I'm " (greeter-name self))))
> (define joe-greet (greeter "Joe"))
> (greeter-name joe-greet)
"Joe"
> (joe-greet "Mary")
"Hi Mary, I'm Joe"
> (joe-greet "John")
"Hi John, I'm Joe
```

### Applying it to typed/racket

Alas, neither syntax works with [`struct`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._struct%29%29) as implemented in `typed/racket`. The problem it seems is that the static type checker as currently implemented cannot both define the structure and resolve its signature as a procedure at the same time. The right information does not appear to be available at the right phase when using `typed/racket`'s `struct` special form.

To get around this, `typed/racket` provides [`define-struct/exec`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._define-struct%2Fexec%29%29) which roughly corresponds to the second syntactic form from `#lang racket` less the keyword argument and property definition:

```
    (define-struct/exec name-spec ([f : t] ...) [e : proc-t])

      name-spec     =       name
                    |       (name parent)
```

> Like define-struct, but defines a procedural structure. The procdure e is used as the value for prop:procedure, and must have type proc-t.

Not only does it give us strongly typed procedural forms, it's a bit more elegant than the keyword syntax found in `#lang racket`. Example code to resolve the question as restated here in this answer is:

```
#lang typed/racket

(define-type 2NN (-> Number Number Number))

(define-struct/exec Cyclic2NN
   ((f : 2NN))
   ((lambda(self x s)
     ((Cyclic2NN-f self) x s))
      : (-> Cyclic2NN Number Number Number)))

 (define-struct/exec SingleBound2NN
   ((f : 2NN))
   ((lambda(self x s)
     ((SingleBound2NN-f self) x s))
       : (-> SingleBound2NN Number Number Number)))

 (define trigFunction1 
   (Cyclic2NN 
    (lambda(x s) 
      (* s (cos x)))))

(define quadraticFunction1
  (SingleBound2NN
    (lambda (x b)
      (let ((x1 x))
        (+ b (* x1 x1)))))
```

The defined procedures are strongly typed in the sense that:

```
> (SingleBound2NN? trigFunction1)
- : Boolean
#f
>  (SingleBound2NN? quadraticFunction1)
- : Boolean
#t
```

All that remains is writing a macro to simplify specification.

Answer (score 6):

In the *general* case, what you want is impossible due to how types are implemented in Racket. Racket has *contracts*, which are run-time wrappers that guard parts of a program from other parts. A function contract is a wrapper that treats the function as a black box - a contract of the form `(-> number? number?)` can wrap any function and the new wrapper function first checks that it receives one `number?` and then passes it to the wrapped function, then checks that the wrapped function returns a `number?`. This is all done *dynamically*, every single time the function is called. Typed Racket adds a notion of types that are statically checked, but since it can provide and require values to and from untyped modules, those values are guarded with contracts that represent their type.

In your function `dispatcher`, you accept a function `f` *dynamically*, at *run time* and then want to do something based on what kind of function you got. But functions are black boxes - contracts don't actually *know* anything about the functions they wrap, they just check that they behave properly. There's no way to tell if `dispatcher` was given a function of the form `(-> number? number?)` or a function of the form `(-> string? string?)`. Since `dispatcher` can accept *any possible function*, the functions are black boxes with no information about what they accept or promise. `dispatcher` can only assume the function is correct with a contract and try to use it. This is also why `define-type` doesn't make a predicate automatically for function types - there's no way to prove a function has the type dynamically, you can only wrap it in a contract and assume it behaves.

The exception to this is arity information - all functions know how many arguments they accept. The [`procedure-arity`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._procedure-arity%29%29) function will give you this information. So while you can't dispatch on function types at run-time in *general*, you *can* dispatch on function *arity*. This is what `case-lambda` does - it makes a function that dispatches based on the number of arguments it receives:

```
(: dispatcher (case-> [-> Calculate-with-one-number Number Void]
                      [-> Calculate-with-two-numbers Number Number Void]))

(define dispatcher
  (case-lambda
    [([f : Calculate-with-one-number]
      [arg : Number])
     (do-something arg)]
    [([f : Calculate-with-two-numbers]
      [arg1 : Number]
      [arg2 : Number])
     (do-something-else arg1 arg2)]
    [else 42]))
```

Comment: I upvoted for the overall explanation and the `case-lambda` solution. But I think the second sentence ("Typed Racket is based on macros that use Racket contracts, which are run-time wrappers...") isn't really correct? Later you do explain that Typed Racket is actually a static, compile-time analysis. All-typed code can be faster precisely because it can _avoid_ contracts, and contract-like runtime tests. Typed Racket uses contracts only to provide a safe runtime interface between typed and _untyped_ code.

Comment: The arity of the functions in the sample code is just coincidental. The example is trivial. What got me thinking about typed functions and dispatching upon them was **occurrence typing**http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/occurrence-typing.html?q=type-case in `typed/racket`.  At this point, I'm thinking I'll probably just box up the functions with `struct` so I can get strong typing by declaration. The cost of boxing/unboxing is probably worth it at this point. Thanks.

Comment: If you can't distinguish the possible dispatch choices by arity, you're definitely better off with boxing/unboxing.

Comment: @Jack Turns out there's no need to box/unbox. In the end, typed/racket allows the language to be extended in the desired direction using structures. See my self-answer.

Comment: @GregHendershott Math was used as domain content, the reason for using `typed/racket` is for more reliable code. The goal was not faster numerical calculations. Using `struct`s which are procedures provides strong typing for functions based on more than airity. See self-answer.